# QuickLook doesn’t work with Chat transcript files

Tags: quicklook, chat

Trying to use QuickLook for Chat transcript files isn’t working anymore on my machine.

First it takes >10 seconds to load (for files <20KB) - and then when it does finally load, it’s just an icon. I can’t actually read the chat.

Anybody else having this experience?

I’m not even quite sure what to try resetting! Deleting the QuickLook plists does not seem to have changed anything.

Comment: What chat transcript? From iChat? From Adium? Is there a standard for chat transcript files?

Comment: Have you installed any QuickLook plugins recently?

Comment: They’re iChat transcript files, and yes, I have installed some QuickLook plugins.

Answer (score 1):

Might want to flush your various caches, specifically font caches - I like [Cocktail](http://www.macupdate.com/app/mac/10909/cocktail) and [Lion Cache Cleaner](http://www.northernsoftworks.com/lioncachecleaner.html) for both.

Comment: Cleaning caches (I used Onyx) didn’t change anything.

Answer (score 0):

Whenever you mess with .qlgenerator files, you should type `qlmanage -r` in the Terminal. This lets the whole QuickLook system know that you have gone around its back, and causes it to nuke its caches and re-initialize everything.

That may be the missing bit. I've known deleted .qlgenerator files to keep working until I did `glmanage -r`.

Before I discovered `qlmanage -r`, I tried emptying the trash after deleting the .qlgenerator file. This caused things to become unstable, and I had to re-boot!